# cakephp 3.0 recaptcha installation

Tags: composer-php, recaptcha, cakephp-3.0

I try to use recaptcha with cakePHP 3.0, but I experience some errors probably dues to a wrong installation.
I work on Windows with composer.
I've add the following lines to composer.json file :

```
"require": {
    (...)
    "google/recaptcha": "~1.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        (...)
        "ReCaptcha\\": "/vendor/google/recaptcha/src/ReCaptcha"
    }
},
```

Then I execute composer cmd to install the plugin:

```
composer update
composer install
composer dumpautoload
```

Finally, I test the plugin in a view :

```
<?php
    $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp);
    if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
        // verified!
    } else {
        $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
    }
?>
```

The result is an error throwed by cake : 
"No secret provided (...) Could this be caused by using Auto-Tables? ..."

Did I correctly installed it ? 
Did I miss or misunderstand something ?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, whatever `$secret` is, it is empty, so you should investigate that.

Comment: That was so simple... Thanks for your observation. Problem solved.

Comment: @ndm why do you use comments instead of answering the question directly?

Comment: @JoséLorenzo Because I'm a lazy ass bastard, and I was worried that this might turn into a "ok, but now ..." question as this seemed a little too easy :) Same with questions that can be easily solved by just reading the docs, I'm most often to lazy to repeat what's already written there, and deep down below I still have the foolish hope that, against all odds, people would try to figure it out by themselves and answer their questions on their own :/

Comment: Note: `composer update` will automatically also `install` and `dumpautoload`, so there is no need to run Composer three times.